# Changes to the apple developer account

Tags: objective-c

Whether the $99 personal accounts can be changed in a $99 enterprise account?
If you can change, please tell me what should to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to talk to Apple. Try the support contacts available to developers via their accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Enterprise account is not charged at $99, however it costs $299 and you can register for Enterprise account from here:

```
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/
```

You need a DUNS number to apply.

However if you just want your company name to be displayed in Developer name, instead of individual name, you need to contact Apple support from here:

```
https://developer.apple.com/contact/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact Apple.

From https://developer.apple.com/support/account/

> #### Can I switch my membership from an individual to an organization?
>
> Yes, if you are the founder/co-founder of the organization. To start the conversion process, please contact us. You may be asked to submit business documents to verify your company's identity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I have to solve this problem。